# How to send multiple parameters to route using flask?

Tags: python, rest, flask, restful-url, flask-restful

I started learning Flask framework recently and made a short program to understand `request/response` cycle in flask.

My problem is that last method called `calc` doesn't work.

I send request as:

> http://127.0.0.1/math/calculate/7/6

and I get error:

> "**Not Found**:
>   The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Below is my flask app code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "&#60;h1&#62;Hello, World!&#60;/h1&#62;"

@app.route('/user/&#60;name&#62;')
def user(name):
    return '&#60;h1&#62;Hello, {0}!&#60;/h1&#62;'.format(name)

@app.route('/math/calculate/&#60;string:var1&#62;/&#60;int:var2&#62;')
def calc(var1, var2):
    return  '&#60;h1&#62;Result: {0}!&#60;/h1&#62;'.format(int(var1)+int(var2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to grab var1 as a string? Have you tried it with <int:var1> ?

Comment: The following is working for me: 

    @app.route('/math/calculate/<int:var1>/<int:var2>')
    def calculate(var1,var2):
        return '<h1>Result %s</h1>' % str(var1+var2)

Comment: @DavidScottIV Thanks man it is working. But My real intent is : http://127.0.0.1:8081/math/calculate/?var1=4&var2=5  how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access request arguments as described in your comment you can use the request library:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/math/calculate/')
def calc():
    var1 = request.args.get('var1',1,type=int)
    var2 = request.args.get('var2',1,type=int)
    return '<h1>Result: %s</h1>' % str(var1+var2)
```

The documentation for this method is documented here:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.args

the prototype of the get method for extracting the value of keys from request.args is:

get(key, default=none, type=none)